# Can't figure out how to do variable substitution in my Tekton pipeline

Tags: bash, tekton, tekton-pipelines, openshift-pipelines

So I'm not sure if this is actually a Bash issue or a Tekton issue. The problem occurs in my OpenShift (Tekton) pipeline. After having deployed my application, I have a step where I need to check if the `Deployment` has actually been created.

This is done like this:

```
until oc get deployment.apps/my-app-foo &> /dev/null
do
  echo . 
  sleep 2
done
```

In the snippet above, I've hardcoded the name of the `Deployment` "my-app". The suffix "-foo" is part of every `Deployment` resource. When hardcoded, it works, and I get my `Deployment`, as expected.

When I try to parameterize the name of the `Deployment`, my pipeline fails with the following error:

```
Error from server (NotFound): deployments.apps "my-app" not found
.
Error from server (NotFound): deployments.apps "my-app" not found
.
Error from server (NotFound): deployments.apps "my-app" not found
.
```

So the issue is obviously that the "-foo" suffix isn't added to my variable, and I can't figure out how to do this. Tried replacing the parentheses with curly braces, tried double quotes around the entire expression, and a few other variants.

Here's my code with variable substitution:

```
until oc get deployment.apps/$(params.pod-name)-foo &> /dev/null
do
  echo . 
  sleep 2
done
```

Can anyone tell what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is `params.pod-name`?

Comment: I do an echo of `params.pod-name` before the `until` loop, and it expands to "my-app" (as expected)

Comment: Then something is very strange there. Bash does not allow `.` and `-` in variable names.

Comment: Ok, I guess this is Tekton syntax then. Here's the docs on variable substitution in Tekton: https://tekton.dev/docs/pipelines/variables/

I'll try to work around it by assigning the Tekton parameter to a bash variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure what the issue is, but seems it has something to do with Tekton variable substitution syntax.

Anyway, I managed to work around it by assigning the Tekton parameter to a bash variable, like this:

```
POD_NAME=$(params.pod-name)
SUFFIX='-foo'
```

And then I used these variables straight forward in the until loop like this:

```
until oc get deployment.apps/${POD_NAME}${SUFFIX} &> /dev/null
do
  echo . 
  sleep 2
done
```

PS. The suffix would probably work fine without being put in a variable, but I'm using it some other places in the same script, so that's why I put it there.